# Review rate-limits not being honored?

Tags: bug

Last night while working through the Reopen votes review queue, I suddenly got the feeling that I had done more than the usual number of reviews. Normally the rate limiter stops me after 20. I hopped over to the history tab and tallied up what I had done since the 0 UTC reset. At that point it was about 24 reviews, IIRC.

I decided to just keep going, thinking perhaps the rate limiter had been changed and I didn't hear about it. After a couple more reviews, I was given the usual notice that I had completed 20 reviews, and to come back tomorrow.

Odd, I thought... but even more odd is I checked back a couple of hours later (well before 0 UTC had come again), and found that it allowed to me to do a few more reviews. It eventually told me again to stop, that I had reached 20. But tallying up my history tab, it looks as if I have actually done 30 in reopen since the last 0 UTC reset.

As of right now, it is offering me posts to review, though I should be locked out currently.

Servy suggested in comments that I am seeing the queue through my filters, and that's why it is not near the 150 limit to raise the rate-limit to 40. I see the queue around 90 right now, and I am not filtering it.

[image]

Comment: @Kendra FWIW, the reopen queue is at 92 right now and still offering to let me review...

Comment: It's showing 157 on my screen right now. It looks like you're just getting lucky on when it's fluctuating.

Comment: @Kendra Seems like a big delta, but I know SO does a lot of caching, so I'll chalk it up to caching. Thanks!

Comment: @DanLowe You're likely looking at the count given the filters you have, not the whole queue.

Comment: @Servy Oh I see filters now. But I have everything checked (presumably the default)